# Add spaces in python list

Tags: python

So this should be super easy but I'm struggling for a while now:
I learn python at moment and there is this Task:
I have string with data, sales data. Name of customer, price of goods etc...

```
daily_sales = """Leticia Manning;,;$15.70 ;,; green&purple;,; 
09/15/17 ,   Mario Wallace ;,; $12.36 ;,;green ;,; 
09/15/17,Lewis Glover;,;   $13.66   ;,;   
green&white;,;09/15/17,   Gail Phelps   ;,;$30.52   
;,; green&white&blue   ;,; 09/15/17 , Myrtle Morris 
;,;   $22.66   ;,; green&white&blue;,;09/15/17"""
```

I want to sort it in to list so it's readable.

```
def sort(daily_sales):
    sales = daily_sales.replace(";,;", "|")
    sales_list = sales.split(",")
    transactions = []
    for objects in sales_list:
        transactions.append(objects.replace(" ", ""))
    return transactions

print(sort(daily_sales))
```

So far so easy. This is my output:

```
['LeticiaManning|$15.70|green&purple|\n09/15/17',
 'MarioWallace|$12.36|green|\n09/15/17',
 'LewisGlover|$13.66|\ngreen&white|09/15/17',
 'GailPhelps|$30.52\n|green&white&blue|09/15/17',
 'MyrtleMorris\n|$22.66|green&white&blue|09/15/17']
```

But i want in front of and after the parting line one empty space. Like:

```
'LeticiaManning | $15.70 | green&purple | \n09/15/17'
```

But i have no idea how to implement it. I tried with .join but obviously it doesn't work. I thought about an interleaved for-loop but i have no idea how this could work.

Comment: in the replace change `'|'` to `' | '`

Comment: That wouldn't work as you remove all spaces in the end.

Comment: Then do it afterwards (before ```print(sorted(...))```)

Comment: You can also remove all the spaces first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove spaces first, then you can insert them after. As a bonus, this saves having to iterate through `sales_list`.

```
def sort(daily_sales):
    sales = daily_sales.replace(" ", "")
    sales = sales.replace(";,;", " | ")
    sales_list = sales.split(",")
    return sales_list

for s in sort(daily_sales):
    print(repr(s))
```

Output:

```
'LeticiaManning | $15.70 | green&purple | \n09/15/17'
'MarioWallace | $12.36 | green | \n09/15/17'
'LewisGlover | $13.66 | \ngreen&white | 09/15/17'
'GailPhelps | $30.52\n | green&white&blue | 09/15/17'
'MyrtleMorris\n | $22.66 | green&white&blue | 09/15/17'
```

Comment: works ! i searched for `repr()` but didn't find a clear definition. what does it ?

Comment: @sanik It returns a string representation of a Python object. See docs: [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr)

Answer (score 2):

Since you get rid of all spaces in this line:

```
transactions.append(objects.replace(" ", ""))
```

you must add them after:

```
transactions.append(objects.replace(" ", "").replace("|", " | "))
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a space before and after each `|`, you can add

```py
t = t.replace("|"," | ")
```

to each transaction.

The full code would look like this:

```py
def sort(daily_sales):
    sales = daily_sales.replace(";,;", "|")
    sales_list = sales.split(",")
    transactions = []
    for objects in sales_list:
        transactions.append(objects.replace(" ", ""))
        transactions[-1] = transactions[-1].replace("|", " | ")
        # add spaces to the new transaction after creating it
    return transactions

print(sort(daily_sales))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, You can also use `re` to add space before and after `|` character 
something like this :

```
import re

daily_sales=['LeticiaManning|$15.70|green&purple|\n09/15/17',
 'MarioWallace|$12.36|green|\n09/15/17',
 'LewisGlover|$13.66|\ngreen&white|09/15/17',
 'GailPhelps|$30.52\n|green&white&blue|09/15/17',
 'MyrtleMorris\n|$22.66|green&white&blue|09/15/17']

data = ''.join(daily_sales)

pattern = re.compile(r"([|])")
print (pattern.sub(" \\1 ", data))
```